# AntiForgeryToken fails to validate in IE when an underscore is present in the subdomain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, antiforgerytoken

This one really has me stumped. My AntiForgeryTokens are working fine in Firefox and IE, however, and ONLY in IE, if there is an underscore '_' in the subdomain of the URL (haven't tried underscore in other locations of URL), it will FAIL to validate every time (regardless of starting with an empty cache with no cookies). What could this mean?

Comment: Ryan, if you examine the POST request from IE using Fiddler or a similar tool, is the request well formatted?  Does the request include the token's cookie and hidden field value?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a known 'bug' of IE, too compliant to specifications.

See [here](http://codingexplorer.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/internet-explorer-cannot-handle-url-with-underscore-%E2%80%9C_%E2%80%9D/) for further information.

Comment: That page you linked no longer exists. Could you please post a new one?